How to prevent multi process pool slow down overtime?
We are trying to run multiple simulation tasks using a multiprocess pool in order to reduce the overall runtime compared to running each task individually in a series. At the beginning of the run CPU and GPU utilization are very high indicating multiple processes running in the background, however, over time the CPU usage drops down to almost 0.
import multiprocessing
import main_mp

def run_sim(process_num, input_list, gpu_device_list):
    """
    multiprocess target function
    :param input_list: list of input files tasks
    :param process_num: process number
    :param gpu_device_list: gpu_device ids for each task
    """
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        print(f"Process number: {process_num} starting")
        main_mp.run_mp_simulation_flow_dist(input_list, gpu_device_list)
        status = "completed"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Process number: {process_num} failed")
        status = "failed"
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        log_process_status(process_num, status, elapsed_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # multi-process parameters
    multi_processes_number = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    gpu_workers = get_cuda_device()
    
    # get file list and split it to tasks
    tuple_file_list = get_files(path)
    data_list, worker_num = split_data(tuple_file_list, args.process_num)
    
    # assign gpus to each task to balance the overall workload
    data_list_sorted = sb.run_sort(data_list, len(gpu_workers))

    total_runtime = 0
    total_start_time = time.time()

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    # run simulation flow
    with multiprocessing.Pool(worker_num) as pool:
        run_times.append(pool.starmap(run_sim,[(i, data_list_sorted[i][0], data_list_sorted[i][1])
                                                for i in range(worker_num)]))

    # close all worker processes
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    total_end_time = time.time()
    total_runtime = total_end_time - total_start_time

    save_log(in_file_list, multi_processes_number, gpu_workers)
    print("multi-process flow completed in ", round(total_runtime/60, 3), " minutes")

environment details: python: 3.12.4 running on an aws instance (g6.24xlarge, 96 vCPUs, 4 nvidia L4 GPUS), cuda 12.3, ubuntu server 24.04.
The simulation is invoked in run_mp_simulation_flow_dist() and utilizes openMP and CUDA, however, we didn't write its code ourselves and therefore do not specifically control how it allocates the machine's resources.
Each process simulation task (invoked in run_sim() and directly in run_mp_simulation_flow_dist()) is composed of sub-tasks that after each one of them is finished, a file is written out to the hard disk. Each one of these sub-tasks is invoked in a series but uses openMP and CUDA for it's speed up. Our expectation was that running 96 process in parallel would speed up the overall runtime of the program. At the beginning the GPU and CPU usage displayed in the terminal is ~95-100% but over time it drops down to 2-4%. Each process doesn't share any objects/parameters we input to it. However more than one process at a time can use some of the same GPU device and apparently some of the same CPU resources as well.
Could this be the result of some process hanging while holding it's allocated resources which results in a domino effect of the entire program slowing down overtime? We tried running the code with a 40 process instead of 96 (leaving more vcpu free for run_mp_simulation_flow_dist()) but the results were the same. Attached is an image of the instance's CPU monitor for the 40 process case.
When running the same code on a Windows 2022 server machine (same HW), no performance drops were shown and the process was parallelized correctly. We tried changing setting the set_start_method value to spawn on the Ubuntu machine and setting max_tasks_per_child to 1 but this didn't help as well. What key difference might be the cause of this?
Running ps afx from the terminal produced the following:
    \_ /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/sim/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(5)
       2941 pts/0    Rl+    8:18  |               \_ /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/sim/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=12) --multiprocessing-fork
       2942 pts/0    Rl+    9:09  |               \_ /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/sim/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=14) --multiprocessing-fork
       2943 pts/0    Rl+    8:33  |               \_ /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/sim/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=6, pipe_handle=16) --multiprocessing-fork

Does the --multiprocessing-fork argument at the end of each process instead of spawn is in order? It also seems that compared to the stage where all system resources are utilized and there is a larger mixture of processes with R1 and D1 status when the SW slows down most of them are with the R1 status. I.e. less overall file writing is being done in a given moment indicating the SW progress slows down.
Can anyone offer some way to resolve this? We appreciate any feedback and assistance with this.

in most cases, GPU resources won' t scale nicely across different processes.
You are in a scenario where your workers, if still needed, should perform CPU related tasks, and call a single (or a few, like 3-4) processes which will deal with all the GPU calls in order -

concurrent.futures won' t do the magic in this case (althugh you can stil use them instead of multiprocessing.Process directly - but with a separate "executor" instance)  - and pass tasks and results back and forth to the GPU-focused processes  in your own code using a multiprocessing.Queue .

what is sb in your code?  (you call sb.run_sort out of nowhere)
